# Конвертировать BSTR* retVal что бы вывести string в printf

Tags: c#, c++, dll

на шарпе написана DLL вызывается в С++, в DLL передаю строку и обратно должен получить строку, но как ее вывести на экран.

строчка

```
printf("%s\n", retVal); //not working
```

С++ проект

```
int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);   //Initialize all COM Components
    MyInterop::IMyDotNetInterfacePtr pDotNetCOMPtr;
    HRESULT hRes =
            pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(MyInterop::CLSID_MyDotNetClass);
    if (hRes == S_OK) {
        BSTR str;
        BSTR* retVal = NULL;
        _bstr_t bstr1("This is the test string.");

        BSTR bstr;

        bstr = bstr1.copy();
        pDotNetCOMPtr->ShowCOMDialog();
        pDotNetCOMPtr->ComeToMe(bstr, retVal);
        printf("%s\n", retVal); //not working
        //call .NET COM exported function ShowDialog ()
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

С# DLL

```
public string ComeToMe(string str) {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(str);
    switch (str) {
        case "Hi":
            return "Hi world";
            break;
    }

    return "Nothing to Show";
}
```

Comment: А если retVal явно преобразовать в string перед выводом?

Comment: Попробуйте почитать здесь(ссылка): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284524/bstr-to-stdstring-stdwstring-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

BSTR не нужно конвертировать, это обычная строка из wchar_t с завершающим нулем. Для вывода можно использовать либо wprintf, либо printf со спецификатором для вывода строк широких символов (`%S` или `%ls`):

```
wprintf(L"%s\n", *retVal);
printf("%S\n", *retVal);
printf("%ls\n", *retVal);
```